# App crash with "Debugging Terminated"

Tags: iphone

I have CLLocation variable declared i gave it a value but when i use it at other place, app crash with "Debugging Terminated" without any logs in console

```
CLLocation *userLoc;

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    userLoc=newLocation;
    [self somefunction];
}
-(void) somefunction
{
NSLog(@"%@",userLoc);
}
```

here it log userLoc properly

but in my other method

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
NSLog(@"%@",userLoc);
}
```

here app crash.
Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Location provides you with autoreleased CLLocation object in delegates method, so it becomes invalid outside that method. To preserve it you need to retain location value:

```
userLoc=[newLocation retain];
```

Or, better, declare a property for your userLoc variable with retain attribute and use it the following way:

```
self.userLoc = newLocation;
```

P.S. [Memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html) is really a must-read...

Comment: i dont have reputation to vote ur answer up...but +1 for ur answer..clearly understood